# Trouble with Selenium property extraction in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the link from a page with Selenium. The code is below:

```
link = 'http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=2120881'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Variants")
elem.click()
time.sleep(2) # wait to load
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[3]/td")
elem = elems[4]
print(elem.get_property('href'))
print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
print(elem.text)
```

Why is the result None when fetching href? How can I obtain this link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works just okay. The problem is in your `xpath`. If you want `a` elements you need to find them and not the outer `td`. Change

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[3]/td")
```

to

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[3]/td/a")
```

(Note `/a` after `/td`)

One more hint:
If you examine `Variants` button, you can see that it also has an url: `http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=2120881#datatab`. You just need to add `#datatab` at the end.

With that said your final script should look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=2120881#datatab'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[3]/td/a")
elem = elems[4]
print(elem.get_property('href'))
print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Much obliged. A perfectly structured and thorough answer.